# Xpath vs DOM vs BeautifulSoup vs lxml vs other Which is the fastest approach to parse a webpage?

Tags: python, dom, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I know how to parse a page using Python. My question is which is the fastest method of all parsing techniques, how fast is it from others?

The parsing techniques I know are Xpath, DOM, BeautifulSoup, and using the `find` method of Python.

Comment: Pick a web page.  Use the `timeit` module to test the execution times of the various mechanisms as they parse your selected source.  Report which one is fastest.

Comment: Ha ha I think now I would because I am wondering about how much can parsing performance vary on x86 and x64 ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/

[image: Comparison]

Comment: So its seems lxml is the fastest of all, now I get it why IBM recommends lxml. Nice thanx :)

Comment: Is BS setup to use lxml as engine?

Answer (score 1):

lxml was written on C. And if you use x86 it is best chose.
If we speak about techniques there is no big difference between Xpath and DOM - it's very quickly methods. But if you will use find or findAll in BeautifulSoup it will be slow than other. BeautifulSoup was written on Python. This lib needs a lot of memory for parse any data and, of course, it use standard search methods from python libs.

Comment: Well said, C written lib is always lot faster than pure Python module. Thanks for the update that lxml is written in C. Wanted to know why did u mention x86. Is it like in x64 something can perform better than lxml, if yes then which one and why?

Comment: x86 or x64 in this context don't have any difference. I mean other platforms, like SPARC or ARM :)

Comment: aaw okies, that wont be a problem in my case :)