# python can't read website html code

Tags: python, urllib

I can't read html code of this [website](https://pinshape.com/shop?page=2) by using urllib

```html
def tests(url):
 response = urllib.urlopen(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
 universities=soup.findAll('a',{'class':'pin-link'})
 print universities

if __name__ == '__main__':
 tests("https://pinshape.com/shop?page=3&is-free=true&type=-streamable")
```

is it possible to read page source ?

Comment: It's not just plain HTML. There is javascript activating a sign in box, which is harder to parse,

Answer (score 0):

You could try using urllib.request. Taking a snippet of part of a code I am using, it works as follows

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://pinshape.com/shop?page=2') as f:
   data = str(f.read()).replace('\n', '')

myfile = open("TestFile.txt", "r+")
myfile.write(data)
```

Comment: urllib.request is for python 3 and above, is there any for python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Despite `urllib`, you can have a try of [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, which is more human-able for beginners to use.

For example, by using `requests`, you can get your webpage like this

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://pinshape.com/shop?page=2")
>>> r.text
>>> u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class=\'no-js\' lang=\'en\'>\n<head>\n<meta charset=\'utf-8\'> ...
```

As a reminder, `BeautifulSoup` is not fast enough, you can have a look at

- [lxml: Benchmarks and Speed](http://lxml.de/performance.html)
- [SO: Xpath vs DOM vs BeautifulSoup vs lxml vs other Which is the fastest approach to parse a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342335/xpath-vs-dom-vs-beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-vs-other-which-is-the-fastest-approach-to)

According to the above posts and my own experience, `lxml` is definitely faster than `BeautifulSoup`. You can check the below link for xpath tutorial

- [W3School: XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're trying to access is HTTPS, notice the 'S', so you need to establish a secure connection. HTTP and HTTPS requests are handled very differently.