# Python HTML web scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm attempting to write a python program to parse the following page and extract the **card sub-brand** and **brand** given the card bin#: https://www.cardbinlist.com/search.html?bin=371793.
The following code snippet retrieves the card type.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.cardbinlist.com/search.html?bin=371793')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print("card type: ", tree.xpath("//td//following::td[7]")[0].text)
```

However, not sure how to get the **brand** using similar logic as given

```
<th>Brand (Financial Service)</th> 
<td><a href="/AMEX-bin-list.html" target="_blank">AMEX</a></td>
```

then

```
tree.xpath("//td//following::td[5]")[0].text
```

returns none.

Comment: Learn enough about "lxml" and/or "tree.path" to try and solve the problem yourself; if you run into problems, come back to SO for help with them.

Comment: The `xpath` is `/html/body/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), as the CSS selectors are more convenient than xpaths.

By using beautiful soup, the code for your problem will be,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

page = requests.get('https://www.cardbinlist.com/search.html?bin=371793')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
brand_parent = soup.find('th', string='Brand (Financial Service)') # selects <th> element which contains text 'Brand (Financial Service)'
brand = brand_parent.find_next_sibling('td').text # O/P AMEX
```

If you want to go with Xpath,

change the xpath to `//td//following::td[5]/a` and try.

Read the following answers to choose your method of scraping,

[Xpath vs DOM vs BeautifulSoup vs lxml vs other Which is the fastest approach to parse a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342335/xpath-vs-dom-vs-beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-vs-other-which-is-the-fastest-approach-to)

[Parsing HTML in python - lxml or BeautifulSoup? Which of these is better for what kinds of purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922032/parsing-html-in-python-lxml-or-beautifulsoup-which-of-these-is-better-for-wha)